# AngularJS can't get selected index of dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this dropdown menu:

```
<select class="form-control" name="timeSlot" ng-model="user.dateTimeSlot" ng-change="dateTimeChanged(user.dateTimeSlot)" ng-blur="blur29=true" required style="float: none; margin: 0 auto;">

                                            <option ng-repeat="x in dateTimeSlots"
                                                    ng-disabled="x.taken"
                                                    ng-value="x.timeSlot">
                                                {{x.dateSlot}}
                                            </option>

                                        </select>
```

And I am trying to get the selected index on the ng-change. However it always returns -1

```
$scope.dateTimeChanged = function (selectedItem) {

        var index = $scope.dateTimeSlots.indexOf(selectedItem);

        console.log(index);

    }
```

Why is it always returning -1....here is a screenshot of my data:

[image]

What I am trying to do is get that id value on the selected item. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is a little uncertain what you really want. Seems to me you are trying to run on two horses :) You bind the `ng-model` to `timeSlot`, but what you really want is the index so you easier can grab the object? What about binding the option values direct to the indexes? :

```
<option ng-repeat="x in dateTimeSlots"
   ng-disabled="x.taken"
   ng-value="{{ $index }}"> <!-- here -->
    {{x.dateSlot}}
</option>
```

now `user.dateTimeSlot` will be 0,1,2,3 and so on (when an option is selected). In the change method you now receive the index

```
$scope.dateTimeChanged = function(selectedItem) {
  console.log($scope.dateTimeSlots[selectedItem]) //<-- the selected object by index
}
```